# MYSQL an after insert trigger to change a fields value

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have two tables stock and order and i am trying to get the trigger to work so that after the an order has been put in the order quantity is then taken away from the stock quantity field.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER stock_update 
AFTER INSERT ON order
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @quantity = NEW.quantity 
UPDATE stock s;
SET s.quantity = OLD.quantity - NEW.quantity
FROM stock s, order o
WHERE s.ID_stock = o.ID_stock;
END;
$$
DELIMITER;
```

but i am just getting the error number 1064

Comment: I think you have a wrong semicolon after `Update stock s`

Comment: agreed. the ; is misplaced there

Comment: Please, post create table statements for both tables

Comment: tried it without the smicolon but still get an error

Comment: i think the code was :mysql> CREATE TABLE stock(         
 ID_stock INT(20) PRIMARY KEY,         
 name VARCHAR(20), 
 priced INT(20),
 quantity INT(20)      
 )

mysql> CREATE TABLE order(         
 ID_order INT(20)  PRIMARY KEY, 
 ID_stock INT(20) FORIGN KEY,        
 quantity INT(20),
 cost INT(20)
 FOREIGN KEY (ID_stock) REFERENCES stock(ID_stock)      
 );

Comment: BTW `order` is not the best name for a table name, since it is a key word (`order by`), so I doubt, you can create a table with that name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. order is a reserved word, therefore you need to use back ticks around it
2. you don't need to use a variable @quantity
3. update statement was wrong
4. DELIMITER and ; should be separated with a space

Try this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER stock_update 
AFTER INSERT ON `order`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE stock s 
   SET s.quantity = s.quantity - NEW.quantity
 WHERE s.ID_stock = NEW.ID_stock;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thanks for the help peterm, after making the change the code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure it will work, since I would need the table definitions in order to test it. 
In each case you should remove the `FROM` clause and also the last line `DELIMITER;`. You 
should also end the line `SET @quantity = NEW.quantity` whith a semicolon.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER stock_update 
AFTER INSERT ON order FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE stock s;
     SET s.quantity = OLD.quantity - NEW.quantity
    WHERE s.ID_stock = NEW.ID_stock;
END;
$$
```